# How to enable macro setting in trust center with a code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in workbook open option to check whether the user is authorized to access the file. However, if the macro setting in trust center for the user is disabled with notification (which is the default setting), he can access the file. What do I need to do to force enable the code to execute irrespective of the macro setting? Once closed, I want the setting to reset to default.

I could not found any good solution apart from enabling macro setting for every user.

Comment: You can't make your code override it. It would make the macro security pointless if you could.

Comment: What If I then open your Excel file in OpenOffice or Google docs?  You cant protect the content of the workbook this way at all, you need a rethink.

Comment: Alex, OpenOffice or Google docs are not available in my office environment so I don't have to worry about that. but if I want to restrict access to the file what method would that be? the file is stored in a shared path

Comment: Set user level permissions on the shared path?

Comment: You could protect your sheets or make them non-visible. Then protect your code. This way no one should be able to get into your editor to make it visible

Comment: You could have the macro documents be signed wuth a digital signature and have only trusted macros enabled (rather than all macros enabled). Of course this may require some input from your workplace IT/security team (or whoever would make that decision).

Answer (score 2):

Create a Worksheet which has a "User not Authorised" message on it.

In the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event, you make this Worksheet Visible, and make **all** other Sheets Very Hidden

In the `Workbook_AfterSave` and `Workbook_Open` events, you check if the user is Authorised.  If so, then you make the normal Worksheets Visible, and make the "User not Authorised" Worksheet Very Hidden.

Make sure that your VBA Project is Protected.  Then, if a User opens the Workbook with Macros Disabled, all that they will be able to see is the "User not Authorised" message.  (You can also add a line such as "If you believe that you are receiving this message in error, please ensure that Macros are Enabled for this Workbook")

Answer (score 2):

Have one introductory worksheet (let's call it "Macros") with a message that macros must be enabled in order to continue. Make this worksheet visible, and all the others Very Hidden.

In the ThisWorkbook module, include the following two subs:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call MacrosOK ' Will only be called if macros are indeed OK.
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Ensures that the macro sheet is always set to the default view when the workbook is saved
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Macros").Visible = True ' Make the macro warning sheet visible
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not sht.Name = "Macros" Then sht.Visible = xlVeryHidden ' Hide all other sheets
    Next sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Then in a regular module:

```
Sub MacrosOK()
    ' Called on open, or otherwise when macros are enabled
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible ' Make all sheets visible
    Next sht
    Sheets("Macros").Visible = xlVeryHidden ' Hide your macro check sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You might want to include a button on the Macro worksheet, labelled "Proceed" (or some such) which is linked to the MacrosOK sub, to enable to user to manually proceed if it does not automatically fire.